# PayPal Webhooks. How can I link a webhook to a previous subscription

Tags: paypal, webhooks, subscription, clientid

Maybe this is a dumb question, but here goes none the less.

I created a webhook and added its clientID to my PayPal-button-container code.
When I have gotten a new subscription purchase with this button, I see that it accesses my webhook when a new BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED fires. This is a live account and a live button. My hope is that the webhook will fire for PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED but this hasn't happened yet.

Here is my real question: what do I have to do to connect this webhook to the subscriptions that did NOT have this clientID in the button when they purchased/set up the subscription. I want this webhook to fire when those accounts process the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED call.

I can put the webhook clientID in the original PayPal-button-container retroactively... but will that work for existing subscriptions?

Or does a webhook work for all payments, and I just haven't seen anything else post yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks only work for payments and subscriptions that were created with that same webhook's client ID.

If payments were created with a *different* client ID, register a webhook event listener for that other client ID.

Comment: Thank you SO much. Now let me look up how to do that!

Comment: Is this actually possible?

Comment: Manage applications in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications . Read the webhooks guide for more information about creating webhooks.

Comment: Hi Preston, I can't find how to register a listener for an existing client ID anywhere. If you've done it or could point to a specific link, I will happily buy you gallons of coffee! That is exactly what I need, and the concept seems straight forward enough. I don't see how PayPal could not have thought of it, nor why they would try so hard to obscure it. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#subscribe-to-events